# Max of a set ,and a limit .

Tags: calculus, limits

a)-Determine :     $$\max \left\{ \sqrt [n] {n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N} ^{\ast }\right\}$$

b)-evaluate :    $$\lim _{x\rightarrow +\infty }\dfrac {x^{x}} {x^{\left( x^{x}\right) }}$$

All this involving the exponential definition of power which states that :
         $$a^{x}=e^{x\ln a}$$

Comment: The answers are $1$ and $0$.  What would you like to know?

Comment: Answers are easy to find by a grapher for instance ,but how ?

Comment: You should show your efforts to solve the problem here, rather than copy/pasting the problem almost verbatim from the book. The first part is tricky, but the second part is almost obvious so that you should have given it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) We suspect that the sequence is *eventually* decreasing.
Indeed, 
$\sqrt[n-1]{n-1}>\sqrt[n]n$ is equivalent to $(n-1)^n<n^{n-1}$, or to $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n>\frac1n$. Let $m:=\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor$. Then using Bernoulli's inequality, we have
$$\begin{align} \left(1-\frac1n\right)^n&=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-m}\\
&\ge\left(1-\frac mn\right)\left(1-\frac {n-m}n\right)\\
&\ge\frac35\cdot\frac12=\frac 3{10},\end{align}$$
provided $n\ge 5$. Thus certainly $\sqrt[n-1]{n-1}>\sqrt[n]n$ for $n\ge 5$. Thus
$$\max\{\,\sqrt[n]n\mid n\in\Bbb N^*\,\}=\max\{1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]3,\sqrt[4]4\}. $$
Of course, $\sqrt[4]4=\sqrt 2$. Note that $\sqrt[3]3>\sqrt 2$ because $3^2>2^3$. Thus finally
$$\max\{\,\sqrt[n]n\mid n\in\Bbb N^*\,\}=\sqrt[3]3.$$

b) Note that for $x>0$, 
$$\ln\frac{x^x}{x^{x^x}}=x\ln x-x^x\ln x=-x^{x-1}\ln x. $$
Clearly, both $x^x$ and $\ln x$  tend $\to +\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. Hence 
$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln \frac{x^x}{x^{x^x}}=-\infty$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^x}{x^{x^x}}=0.$$

Comment: For the limit the graph says something other that infinity

Comment: It yields to 0  .

Comment: @DamilaWhiShadow Yeah, sign error in the log ... adjusted

Comment: Okey yup .i'm grateful !

Comment: I enjoyed your solution for case a, however is different from mine.

Comment: There is typo in your second last equation. You should get $x(1-x^{x-1})\ln x$ instead of $-x^{x-1}\ln x$. The answer remains same however.

Answer (score 1):

a) Let $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then $y'=(1-\ln(x))\frac{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}$. Hence, for $x>e$, $y'<0$ and $y$ is increasing, and for $x<e$, $y'>0$ and $y$ is decreasing. Now let $x\in\mathbb{N}$ the maximum value for $y$ has to be check between $2$ and $3$ only as $2<e<3$ so one of $3$ or $2$  give the maximum. $n=3$ gives the maximum.

b) $\lim\frac{x^x}{x^{(x^x)}}=\lim\frac{1}{x^{(x^x-x)}}=\lim\frac{1}{x^{x(x^{x-1}-1)}}=0$

Answer (score 1):

For part a) the best approach is the one in Hagen von Eitzen's answer. The second part is almost trivial. If $x>2$ then $x^{x} >x^{2}$ and hence we have $x^{x^{x}} >x^{x^{2}}$ and thus we can see that for $x>2$ we have $$0<\frac{x^{x}}{x^{x^{x}}}<\frac{x^{x}}{x^{x^{2}}}=\frac{1}{x^{x^{2}-x}}<\frac{1}{x}$$ and hence by Squeeze theorem we see that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{x}} {x^{x^{x}}} =0$$